# Sending data from one .NET app to another

Tags: c#, rest, wcf, json.net, .net-remoting

I've found answers to this question going for WCF but they're from 2013 and I was wondering if something has changed.

I write plugins for a third-party application that loads the plugins as `COM`. It also loads all plugins in the same context which caused problems for me in the past with my own dependency assemblies but I solved this by strong-naming all assemblies and thus being able to load different versions of the same DLL into the context (in case the user uses several of my plugins).

Now I have an external app that should send data to the plugin to be processed further. My first approach was to use `OWIN` as a REST self-host and just add a controller. Unfortunately that whole architecture is tightly bound to `Newtonsoft.Json` and those DLLs are not strongly named, i.e. cause problems when you have other plugins getting the same idea but using older/newer versions of the assembly.

So I was wondering what else I could use that ideally is built-in to .NET. Remoting? WCF after all? Something newer I'm not aware of?

Comment: Once you start reading [WCF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/whats-wcf), passing data will become very obvious. This is an article describing how to handle [callbacks and events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2006/october/wcf-working-with-one-way-calls-callbacks-and-events) in WCF.

Comment: You may also have a look to gRPC for .NET, but that is not built-in. Or use named pipes, that are easy to use. Your selection depends on your detailed requirements, e.g. security, configurablibity etc.